# Classic theme in yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to yii framework and i'm learning it from online tutorials and yii documentations.I found that i don't have some files in Themes directory which i saw in tutorial.As you can see in the attached file that `layouts` and `site` folder contains file (`main.php` and `index.php`) and in my PC i just have folders.

[image]

Comment: check them in `view` folder inside `protected` folder.

Comment: What tutorial were you following? The theme structure on your PC is the default Yii theme structure for a new application

Comment: check page # 200 @ [link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/92201306/yii-guide-1-1-8) . Also if its the default theme then how would i change this default theme

Comment: @itachi thank u so much, i got it. can you please tell me if i want to change is this the only area

Comment: To change the look of the website, you will be editing _protected/views/layouts/main.php_, (and possible the other layouts in there) which is your wrapper layout, inside there is `echo $content;` which is where the view files are rendered. Controller/Actions which have a `render` function render a view (which is in the _protected/views/controller name/.._). So you will be editing those. And then of course your CSS files in _css/_

Comment: No problem, I know it didn't really answer your question about the themes, but hopefully it will help you in customizing your app styling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main file to change the theme is located at `protected/views/layouts/main.php`